# Conditional Proof that uses the basic 9 inferences. Can you Please help

Tags: philosophy-of-logic

Conditional Proof that uses the basic 9 inferences. I know assumption and indentation is required. Can you Please help

1. ~P
2. (S>Q) /(PvS)>Q

Comment: What are those 9 basic inference rules?

Answer (score 2):

If you give a list of the 9 basic rules, I can make this more specific to your proof system. Your notation looks a little strange, but I think the task is to assume:

1. ¬P,
2. S → Q

and establish:

3. (P ∨ S) → Q.

The shape of the conclusion suggests that we attempt to prove this directly: by assuming the antecedent (P ∨ S) and trying to derive the consequent (Q). So assume (P ∨ S). Now we proceed by cases: assume P and get some conclusion X, assume S and get that same conclusion X, and conclude that X.

- Assume P. From premise (1) we know that ¬P, so we have a contradiction. From a contradiction any proposition follows, so we can simply conclude that Q is true.
- Assume S. From premise (2) we know that if S then Q, so with our assumption, by *modus ponens*, we know that Q is true.

Since Q follows from both the P case and the S case, we conclude, by *disjunction elimination* (or [proof by cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_exhaustion)), that Q is true. Finally, since this conclusion Q was reached by the outermost assumption (P ∨ S), we know, by *conditional introduction* (or [direct proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_proof)) that (P ∨ S) → Q.